# PHP Web App - local and online synced versions

Tags: php

I developed a PHP driven Web App with a MySQL backend. New requirement is to have it available offline too at a client's office, once there is an lnternet connection, the two should sync so that both local and online versions are the same. Any advice on how best to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I found MySQL database Master-Master Replication helpful.

https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/configure-master-master-mysql-database-replication

no need to write code